# How to call shell script from another shell script from another user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to call shell script from another shell script from another user?

Can you please share the sample code?

I have two scripts:

showdate.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Date is : `date`"
```

and mainscript.sh:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 su - nmsadm 
 echo " You are logged in as `whoami`"
 echo "`./showdate.sh`"
```

When I am executing mainscript I want to switch to other user and run showdate script.

Here is the output

```
#./mainscript.sh    
You have new mail.
-bash-3.2$
```

It switches to nmsadm user but does not execute show script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the script as another user, use the following syntax:

```
sudo -u nsadm ./showdate.sh
```

Make sure the `showdate` script is executable